# PHP - date(time) insert into DB

Tags: php, mysql, sql, time, insert

I'm using a time method: 
   `$time= date('h:i:s');`

What I want is to put this time into database in mySQL, 
I used:
    `$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tab ('ltime') VALUES ($time)");` but it's not working

Where tab is a table and a ltime is a Column with time Type.

What am I doing wrong?

Regards

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: remove the ' ' from ltime

Comment: Possible duplicate of [When to use single quotes, double quotes, and backticks in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11321491/when-to-use-single-quotes-double-quotes-and-backticks-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1):

Your query will goes like this.

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tab (ltime) VALUES ('$time')");
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query should be like this

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tab (ltime) VALUES ($time)");
```

Comment: check the value in your $time variable it must be $time = date('h:i:s') format

Comment: It is $time = date('h:i:s') and still there is 00:00:00 in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Columns and tables should have backticks and not single quotes

```
INSERT INTO `tab` (`ltime`) VALUES ($time)
```

Comment: It's not working, if I'm checking my DB there is still a 00:00:00

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tab (ltime) VALUES ($time)");
```

Don't use '' when assigning the column name

Answer (score 0):

The first way specifies both the column names and the values to be inserted:

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

If you are adding values for all the columns of the table, you do not need to specify the column names in the SQL query

```
INSERT INTO table_name VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

In your case:

```
$query = mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO tab (ltime) VALUES ($time)");
```

there is no need to single quote with column name:

Reference: https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_insert.asp